# General solution to 3D linear 2nd order PDE using Wronskian and Integrals?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, vector-analysis

Using the Wronskian and Indefinite Integrals, I can write the solution to the general one dimensional second order linear non-homogeneous differential equation
$$
y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=g(x)
\\
y^*(x)= y_2(x)\int \dfrac{y_1(x)g(x)}{W(x)} dx
\\
y_1(x)\int \dfrac{y_2(x)g(x)}{W(x)} dx
\\
W(x) = e^{-\int p(x) dx}= y_2'(x)y_1(x)-y_1'(x)y_2(x)
\\
y_1''+p(x)y_1'+q(x)y_1=y_2''+p(x)y_2'+q(x)y_2=0
$$

however I am puzzled on how to generalize this prescribed solution to its three dimensional equivalent. I assume the general 3D equivalent is
\begin{align}
\nabla^2 y+\boldsymbol{p}\cdot \boldsymbol{\nabla}y+qy=g
\end{align}
where $\boldsymbol{p}$ may have to be curl free.

Does there exist a known solution to the general solution to the three dimensional linear second order partial differential equation using the Wronskian and Indefinite Integrals?